# JAVA new Timestamp() make ending ZERO disappear when time in ms end with ZERO

Tags: java, timestamp

In my logs I am using : (java.sql.Timestamp)

```
 new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

it behaves strangely (IMHO) :

- when System.currentTimeMillis() =  1490713735960

  > it returns : **2017-03-28 17:08:55.96**

### I expected to have : 2017-03-28 17:08:55.96**0** with an ending 0

- when System.currentTimeMillis() =  1490713724721

  > it returns : 2017-03-28 17:08:44.721

  as expected

### Questions :

Is this a normal behavior of new Timestamp() ?

Why the terminating ZERO is being dropped ?

Comment: I suppose `java.sql.Timestamp` right ?

Comment: yes : java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes it is the correct behaviour. Because the implementation of `toString()` method for the nanoseconds part is:

```
if (nanos == 0) {
    nanosString = "0";
} else {
    nanosString = Integer.toString(nanos);
    ...
}
```

In the `else` part:

```
// Truncate trailing zeros
char[] nanosChar = new char[nanosString.length()];
nanosString.getChars(0, nanosString.length(), nanosChar, 0);
int truncIndex = 8;
while (nanosChar[truncIndex] == '0') {
    truncIndex--;
}

nanosString = new String(nanosChar, 0, truncIndex + 1);
```

Have a look at source code of `java.sql.Timestamp.toString()` method